# Как научить python распознавать изображение, на котором находится график?

Tags: python, изображения, график

У меня вопрос такой, как научить python распознавать изображение, на котором находится график, с которого нужно считать данные.

Может кто-то посоветовать, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Что вы уже прочитали сами по этому поводу и какие конкретные трудности у вас в реализации намеченного?

Answer (score 1):

*Так как надо посоветовать, я советую)*

Первым делом возьмите библиотеку для работы с изображениями. Необходимым функционалом для вас будут методы для открытия изображения из файлов и чтение цвета пикселя в конкретной точки.

Теперь определите цвет графика на изображении. Можно сделать с помощью фотошопа, паинта, не важно.

После мы должны загрузить в питоне наше изображения, и пройтись по изображению слева на право столбиками. В каждом столбике ищем пиксель нужного цвета, при этом желательно игнорировать маленькую ошибку: когда цвета различаются очень слабо (например из за сжатия) точная проверка точно пропустит его. Поэтому вычисляйте общую ошибку (например суммой ошибок каждого цветового канала: `abs(source.r - selected.r) + abs(source.g - selected.g) + abs(source.b - selected.b)`) и проверяйте, что бы она была меньше установленной. Как только нашли сохраняем его и переходим к следующему столбику. Таким образом мы получим высоту графика в каждый конкретный момент времени.

Если вы хотите получить формулу, то простых способов тут нет. Единственный вариант который я вижу: полиномы. Любой график можно аппроксимировать к полиному с достаточным количеством параметров.

Comment: Ответ замечательный, только не паинт, а пэйнт, скорей)